# Why when processing JVMTI EVENT_EXCEPTION the JVM sometimes crashes or starts slowly?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, jvm-hotspot, jvmti

I decided using JVMTI to register all exceptions occured in JVM and build Histogram: 
*ClassName_method_ExceptionName:count*

Agent attached like this:
 *taskset -c 10,12 java -agentpath:./jni-agent.so ${JVM_OPTION} -cp module.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher &*

I using this code for JNI agent:

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jvmti.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include "utils.h"

long excCount;
using namespace std;

map<string, long> mapExceptions;
map<string, long> mapContendedThreadStack;

void mapAddException(map<string,long> &inMap, string key){
    map<string, long> :: iterator it = inMap.find(key);
    if(it == inMap.end()){
        inMap.insert(pair<string, long>(key,1));
        return;
    }
    inMap.find(key)->second ++;
    return;
}
..
..

void JNICALL ExceptionCallback(jvmtiEnv* jvmti, JNIEnv *env, jthread thread, jmethodID method,     jlocation location,
jobject exception, jmethodID catch_method, jlocation catch_location) {
    excCount ++;
    char *class_name;
    jclass exception_class = env->GetObjectClass(exception);
    jvmti->GetClassSignature(exception_class, &class_name, NULL);

    char* method_name;
    jvmti->GetMethodName(method, &method_name, NULL, NULL);
    jclass holder;
    jvmti->GetMethodDeclaringClass(method, &holder);

    char* holder_name;
    jvmti->GetClassSignature(holder, &holder_name, NULL);
    if(strstr(holder_name, "java/lang") != NULL
        || strstr(holder_name, "java/net") != NULL
        || strstr(holder_name, "sun/reflect") != NULL
        || strstr(holder_name, "org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection") != NULL
        || strstr(holder_name, "okhttp3/internal/connection/RealConnection") != NULL
        || strstr(holder_name, "okio/AsyncTimeout") != NULL ){
            jvmti->Deallocate((unsigned char*) method_name);
            jvmti->Deallocate((unsigned char*) holder_name);
            jvmti->Deallocate((unsigned char*) class_name);
            return;
    }
    string trimres = trimClassName(convertToString(holder_name, strlen(holder_name)));      
    char buftotal[1024];
    snprintf(buftotal, sizeof(buftotal) - 1, "%s#%s()_%s", trimres.c_str(), method_name, trimClassName(class_name).c_str());
    replacechar(buftotal, '/', '.');
    
    //mapAddException(mapExceptions, buftotal);       <-- HERE 

    jvmti->Deallocate((unsigned char*) method_name);
    jvmti->Deallocate((unsigned char*) holder_name);
    jvmti->Deallocate((unsigned char*) class_name);
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, char *options, void *reserved) {

    jvmtiCapabilities capabilities;
    jvmtiEventCallbacks callbacks;
    jvmtiEnv *jvmti;

    vm->GetEnv((void **) &jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1_0);
    printf("\nNative agent loaded by -agent.....\n");
    capabilities = {0};
    capabilities.can_generate_exception_events = 1;
    jvmti->AddCapabilities(&capabilities);
    callbacks = {0};
    callbacks.Exception = ExceptionCallback;
    jvmti->SetEventCallbacks(&callbacks, sizeof(callbacks));
    jvmti->SetEventNotificationMode(JVMTI_ENABLE, JVMTI_EVENT_EXCEPTION, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

With commented line mapAddException(...) the JVM started  much longer than without the JNI-agent.
Is this Ok ?
I forgot to say - this is Spring Boot application with "Hello World" all ok :)

But when I uncommented mapAddException(...) JVM sometimes crashed. Not at all, sometimes(~ 2-4 of 50).

This is cut from  CrashDump:

```
..
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f32781bf0b4, pid=47559, tid=0x00007f31e29e1700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_231-b11) (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.231-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libstdc++.so.6+0x750b4]
..
#
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f3275d82000):  JavaThread "tomcat-thread-16" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=47682, stack(0x00007f31e28e1000,0x00007f31e29e2000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000010

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007f3190009340, RCX=0x0000000000000001, RDX=0x00007f3274ba0eb0
RSP=0x00007f31e29dc7c8, RBP=0x00007f327414fea0, RSI=0x00007f32786541d0, RDI=0x00007f327414fea0
R8 =0x0000000000000002, R9 =0x0000000000000030, R10=0x000000000000000c, R11=0x00007f327a316f40
R12=0x00007f31a00504f0, R13=0x00007f32786541c8, R14=0x00007f32786541d0, R15=0x00007f3190009340
RIP=0x00007f32781bf0b4, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010283, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
....
```

The Current thread are different every time at CrashDump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The crash reason is simple: your code is not thread safe.**

Exception callback is invoked on the same thread that throws an exception. If multiple threads throw an exception concurrently, the callback is also invoked concurrently. `std::map` is not thread safe: concurrent access may cause a crash inside libstdc++.

**The reason of slowness is more interesting.**

How to analyze performance issues related to interaction between JVM and native? With [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/), of course. When profiling application startup, it's convenient to start profiler as an agent.

```
java -agentpath:/path/to/libasyncProfiler.so=start,event=cpu,file=out.svg -agentpath:./your-agent.so -cp ...
```

When I compared profiles with and without your agent, I noticed one major difference. With the agent, there was a noticeable `[deoptimization]` block on the left side:

[image: deopt.png]

Why does deoptimization happen? async-profiler will help again: let's profile `Deoptimization::deoptimize` event now. It's not really an event, this is just a function name in HotSpot JVM (async-profiler can trace invocations of native functions).

```
java -agentpath:/path/to/libasyncProfiler.so=start,event=Deoptimization::deoptimize,file=deopt.svg ...
```

There was more than 8000 deoptimization events! Here is just a small part of the graph:

[image: deopt2.png]

Most deoptimizations originate from `exception_handler_for_pc_helper`. If we look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/73f624a2488d/src/share/vm/c1/c1_Runtime1.cpp#l493) of this function, we'll see an interesting comment:

```
  if (JvmtiExport::can_post_on_exceptions()) {
    // To ensure correct notification of exception catches and throws
    // we have to deoptimize here.

    <...>

    // We don't really want to deoptimize the nmethod itself since we
    // can actually continue in the exception handler ourselves but I
    // don't see an easy way to have the desired effect.
    Deoptimization::deoptimize_frame(thread, caller_frame.id());
```

What this means is - when JVM TI Exception notifications are on, HotSpot forces deoptimization every time an exception happens in the compiled code! This can surely hit performance if exceptions are frequent.

**How to analyze exceptions without JVM TI overhead then?**

At this point you may already guess the answer - with async-profiler again :) Besides CPU and native function profiling, it can also intercept any Java method call.

To find all places where exceptions and errors are created, we can just intercept `Throwable` constructors. To do so, specify `java.lang.Throwable.<init>` as async-profiler event. This time it's handy to produce a reversed call tree (add `reversed,file=tree.html` options), so that throwables will be grouped by the type and the construction site.

```
java -agentpath:/path/to/libasyncProfiler.so=start,event=java.lang.Throwable.\<init\>,reverse,file=tree.html ...
```

This will produce an interactive HTML tree, where you'll find all exceptions with counters and full stack traces:

[image: tree.png]

Ouch! A simple Spring Boot application throws 4700 exceptions: most of them are `ClassNotFoundException` (90%) and `NoSuchMethodException` (7%).

What is important, async-profiler uses bytecode instrumentation for method tracing, so it does not suffer from the performance problem of JVM TI exception callback.

**Bonus**

When profiling your agent for the first time, besides the deoptimization issue, I also found a decent number of stack traces where CPU time is spent in your `ExceptionCallback` calling `GetMethodDeclaringClass` and `GetMethodName`:

[image: method.png]

This is actually a performance bug in JDK 8, which I reported 3 years ago: [JDK-8185348](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185348). At last, it has been fixed in JDK 8u281. However, there was no such problem in JDK 9+.

In short, since all JVM TI Method functions are slow, it is a good idea to cache the result of these functions, so that the agent will not call JVM TI function for the same method more than once.

Comment: Very detailed and excellent answer as usually ! It's very sad that JVMTI make Deoptimization and impact on performance. I need time to think about this. Thanks!

Comment: What about another  events like MONITOR_CONTENDED_ENTER,COMPILED_METHOD_LOAD, DYNAMIC_CODE_GENERATED. Is there deoptimization for them to ?

Comment: @srg321 No, these events do not require deoptimization. BTW, since you understand Russian, I can recommend you [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiuKiE5-0g4) about JVM TI. It also mentions the above problems of Exception Callbacks and slow Method functions.